# amcharts - export chart using my own buttons outside of the chart

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to invoke export with my own buttons, outside of the chart, but am getting the following error :

`TypeError: AmCharts.AmExport is not a constructor`

I was using an example I found on stackoverflow at http://jsfiddle.net/BGuuT/2/ which works by the way, but doesn't seem to in my own implementation for some reason. Maybe I have a newer version?

I am including in my page :

```
amcharts-3.21.12/amcharts.js
amcharts-3.21.12/serial.js
amcharts-3.21.12/plugins/export/export.js
```

html is :

```
<ul id="chart-selector">
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="JPG">JPG</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="PNG">PNG</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="SVG">SVG</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="CSV">CSV</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="JSON">JSON</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="PDF">PDF</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="XLSX">XLSX</li>
    <li class="dropdown-item" data-click="PRINT">Print</li>
</ul>
```

I am getting the correct export value to pass here, but the constructor error still shows :

```
chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chart_chart", { .......... });

$('body').on('click', '#chart-selector .dropdown-item', function(e) {

    var test = $(this).data('click');

    //chart download action
    var exp = new AmCharts.AmExport(chart);
        exp.init();
        exp.output({
            format: test
        });
});
```

The only difference I can see between the mine and the link given is export.js compared to amexport_combined.js - the latter is not a file given in amcharts though. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example is using a very old version of the export plugin. There are knowledge base examples on AmCharts' site that use the current version of the plugin for AmCharts v3:

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/export-chart-data-to-json-csv-and-excel-via-api/
https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/export-charts-advanced/

The main idea is to use the export's `capture` method to capture the state of the chart for an image-based format, use the `to*` methods to make the format conversion, then call `download` in the callback. For data-based formats such as CSV, JSON, and XLSX, just call the associated `to*` method then `download`

For JPG:

```
  chart.export.capture({}, function() {
    this.toJPG({}, function(data) {
      this.download(data, this.defaults.formats.JPG.mimeType, "amCharts.JPG");
    });
```

For CSV

```
  chart.export.toCSV({}, function(data) {
    this.download(data, this.defaults.formats.CSV.mimeType, "amCharts.csv");
  });
```

(Note that disabling the export plugin's internal dropdown is done by setting `menu: []` in the export config.)

Here's an example invoking the export API through your buttons: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/36056b016c577dc6bc5b4a40120fc71c

Comment: Alright - I had looked on the site, but couldn't find examples using them in this manner or the api.  I guess I didn't look hard enough - only saw methods for using the default button inside the chart.  Thank you - I will go over this and see what happens.

Comment: Is there a setting for AmCharts.makeChart to define where the js is located?  I am getting the following when the chart is created due to the new export options added to it : `Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://site.local/assets/js/plugins/export/libs/fabric.js/fabric.min.js”.` and so on for FileSaver, jszip, pdfmake

Comment: Look at the export documentation for the [`libs`](https://github.com/amcharts/export/#user-content-loading-external-libraries-needed-for-operation-of-this-plugin) setting, since it looks like you moved the plugin files. It also considers the [`path`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#path) property as well. Personally, I'd just keep the amcharts folder heirarchy instead of moving things out since the chart and plugins are distributed together, but that's up to you.

Comment: Yeah I just saw the path option.  Everything is part of a build process so I'll figure something else out for this - even if its just manually copying the needed files to where they need to be.